# How many days did Esther fast?

Tags: megillat-esther, esther--the-woman, maharal, avraham-ibn-ezra

How many days did Esther fast? Avraham ibn Ezra said it was two days and two nights. And Maharal said it was 70 hours of fasting. How do you reconcile these arguments (opinions)? Is it possible to fast for three days, day and night? Was it intermittent? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Many mekubalim have the minhag to fast for 3 days and 3 nights straight. It is certainly possible, especially for our generation which carries around great reserves of nutrition, if you catch my drift.

Comment: Thank you very much Akhi.